# Noob Concern: Converting Dec to String C#

Tags: c#

I am calling a method that returns a decimal, which I need to display in a textbox.

```
tbxDisplayCost.Text = dinnerFun.CalcTotalCost(cbxHealthy.Checked);
```

It's saying I can't implicitly convert dec to string...

So I tried two things (probably incorrectly)

```
tbxDisplayCost.Text = dinnerFun.CalcTotalCost(cbxHealthy.Checked).ToString;
tbxDisplayCost.Text = (string)dinnerFun.CalcTotalCost(cbxHealthy.Checked);
```

Neither worked... and I'm kinda scratching my head to figure out how I can get that returned dec to be displayed in the textbox...

Comment: The ToString on the first example should be ToString()

Comment: +1 for a relatively good question, with what you've tried first before asking here, and a better description of the problem than "got an error".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So close:

```
tbxDisplayCost.Text = dinnerFun.CalcTotalCost(cbxHealthy.Checked).ToString();
```

And if you don't like the format when it comes out, you can tweak things with a [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) or [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) format string argument.

Answer (score 4):

The first line is trying to use a *method group* (the name of the method without the brackets) - it's not *calling* the `ToString` method, which is what I suspect you intended. To do that you want:

```
tbxDisplayCost.Text = dinnerFun.CalcTotalCost(cbxHealthy.Checked).ToString();
```

The second line is trying to just *cast* the value, which won't work as there's no *explicit* conversion from `decimal` to `string` either.

For clarity I'd quite possibly separate the "calculation" step from the "display" step:

```
decimal cost = dinnerFun.CalcTotalCost(cbxHealthy.Checked);
tbxDisplayCost.Text = cost.ToString();
```

Note that you might want to provide a [numeric format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) to `ToString`, e.g.

```
decimal cost = dinnerFun.CalcTotalCost(cbxHealthy.Checked);
tbxDisplayCost.Text = cost.ToString("c"); // Display as a currency value
```